# Can't use Vuex to store the method function

Tags: api, vue.js, vuex

I wan't to use Vuex to the methods function (from my **home.js**) to get the weather data from the api to display on browser, I have tried to use getters and put it in computed but it didn't work.
This is my **home.js**:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import Diagramm from '../diagramm/Diagramm.vue';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import Temperature from '../temperature/Temperature.vue';
import Header from '../header/Header.vue';
import NextDays from '../nextdays/NextDays.vue';
import {mapState, mapGetters} from 'vuex';

import '../../custom.scss';

export default {

    components: {
        Header,
        Diagramm,
        Temperature,
        NextDays
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isShown: false,
            api_key: '',
            url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
            query: '',
            weather: {},
            icons: {
                'Rain': require('../../assets/regnerisch.png'),
                'Clear': require('../../assets/sonne.png'),
                'Clouds': require('../../assets/wolkig.png'),
                'Snow': require('../../assets/schnee.png'),
                'Drizzle':require('../../assets/regnerisch.png'),
                'Thunderstorm':require('../../assets/regnerisch.png')
            },
            /*weather in next days */
            weathers: [],
            PREFERRED_TIME: '12:00:00',
            DAYS: ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'],
            /*Chart*/
            dates: [],
            temps: [],
            scaleFontColor:'white'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        removeType(event) {
            this.query = ''
        },
        /* current location weather forecast */
        currentCity() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                    axios
                    fetch(`${this.url_base}weather?&lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
                        .then(res => {
                            return res.json();
                        }).then(this.setResultsCurrentWeather);
                    })
                };

            },  

        setResultsCurrentWeather(results) {
            this.weather = results;
        },
/* today temperature */
        fetchWeather() {
            fetch(`${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
                .then(res => {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(this.setResults);
        },
        setResults(results) {
            this.weather = results;
        },

...

mounted() {
        this.fetchWeather(); /* today temperature */
        this.currentCity();
        this.ForeCastOfCurrentCity();
        this.$store.dispatch('currentCity');
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchWeather');
    },
    computed:{
        currentCity(){
            return this.$store.dispatch('currentCity');
        },
        fetchWeather(){
            return this.$store.dispatch('fetchWeather');
        }
    }
```

And this is my **Home.vue**:

```
<b-sidebar
      id="sidebar-right"
      right
      shadow
      bg-variant="black"
      img
      src="@/assets/suchen.png"
      text-variant="white"
    >
      <div slot="title">
        <img src="@/assets/suchen.png" class="search-icon" />
      </div>
      <div class="px-3 py-2">
        <img src="@/assets/close_white.png" class="close-white-icon" @click="removeType()" />
        <input
          class="input"
          v-model="query"
          v-on:keyup.enter="fetchWeather(), fetchWeatherForecast(), getData()"
        />
        <hr style="background-color:white" class="hr2" />
      </div>
    </b-sidebar>

... 

<Temperature  :weather="weather"></Temperature>

My **Temperature.vue**( child component of **Home**):
<b-row v-if="typeof weather.main != 'undefined'">
      <b-col cols="8" sm="8" md="9" lg="9" xl="8" class="number">
        <b-row>
          <b-col cols="4" sm="5" lg="6" xl="7"></b-col>
          <b-col cols="6" sm="6" lg="5" xl="4">
            <b-col cols="4" sm="8" lg="2"></b-col>
            <b-col cols="2" sm="4" lg="10">
              <p class="main-temp">{{ Math.round(weather.main.temp)}}</p>
              <img :src="icons[weather.weather[0].main]" class="main-icon"/>
              <p class="max-temp">{{ Math.round(weather.main.temp_max) }}°C</p>
              <p class="min-temp">{{ Math.round(weather.main.temp_min) }}°C</p>
              <b-row>
                <img src="@/assets/humidity.png" class="humidity-icon" />
              </b-row>
              <b-row>
                <img src="@/assets/wind.png" class="wind-icon" />
              </b-row>
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="humidity">%</b-col>
            <b-col class="humidity-number">{{ Math.round(weather.main.humidity) }}</b-col>
            <b-col class="wind-number">
              <p>{{ Math.round(weather.wind.speed) }}</p>
              <p></p>
              <p class="nph">nph</p>
            </b-col>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
      </b-col>
      <b-col cols="1" sm="1" md="1" lg="1" xl="3" class="grad">
        <img src="@/assets/grad.png" class="grad-size" />
      </b-col>

      <b-col cols="3" sm="3" md="2" lg="2" xl="1" class="sonne"></b-col>
    </b-row>
```

And my **store.js**:( I'm not sure if the actions and mutations are correct.)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced:true,
    state: {
        weather:{},
        api_key: '',
        url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
        query: '',
        icons: {
            'Rain': require('../assets/regnerisch.png'),
            'Clear': require('../assets/sonne.png'),
            'Clouds': require('../assets/wolkig.png'),
            'Snow': require('../assets/schnee.png'),
            'Drizzle':require('../assets/regnerisch.png'),
            'Thunderstorm':require('../assets/regnerisch.png')
        },          
    },
     actions:{
        currentCity({commit}) {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                    axios
                    fetch(`${this.url_base}weather?&lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
                        .then(res => {
                            commit('CUR_CITY',res.json()) ;
                        }).then(this.setResultsCurrentWeather);
                    })
                };

            },  

        setResultsCurrentWeather(results) {
            this.weather = results;
        },
     },
     mutations:{
         CUR_CITY (state, weather){
             state.weather = weather
         }
     }
})
```

**main.js**:

```
import store from './store/store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts, Column2D, FusionTheme);
Vue.prototype.moment = moment

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.

Comment: try to start with dead simple example: https://github.com/JiriChara/vuex-crud

Comment: Thank you for your vuex example. However my API still works fine. You can see it on : https://github.com/mailinhpham2401/weather-app

Comment: Had a look at your github code, it seems you have defined vuex store, but not imported in main.js , you need to add store like  --------import store from './store/store'; new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router,store
}).$mount('#app')

Comment: @Manoj I've tried to import it but it still gives an error: "[vuex] unknown action type: CUR_CITY". This is my new responsitory with **store** imported in it : https://github.com/mailinhpham2401/weather_app_vuex_test

Comment: @Mai I had a look at your new code. Console error is saying- [vuex] unknown action type: CUR_CITY, this is because in your main.js you have given ...mapActions(["CUR_CITY"]), but you have no such action your store.js. It would be fine in home.js mounted hook- write--- this.$store.dispatch('currentCity'). This will dispatch the action in your store. Also, I tried this and it did trigger the action in your store but the fetch api seems to giving error. once you correct your api, your mutation is correct and you can access weather state in you home.js via mapState and use it in home.vue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for home and temperature components with store. you can modify other components in similar way.
https://github.com/manojkmishra/weather_app_vuex_test
https://weather-app-vuex-test.netlify.app/

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
state: { weather:{},    },
 actions:{
    async currentCity ({commit}, position)
    {   let url_base= 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/';
        let api_key= 'c9f562aaffcdefaf40f2ed808d202c9b';
        console.log('store-pos',position,url_base,api_key)
        let res=await   
axios.get(`${url_base}weather?&lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${
            position.coords.longitude}&units=metric&APPID=${api_key}`)
            commit('CUR_CITY',res.data)
        return res;
    },
 },
 mutations:{
     CUR_CITY (state, weather)
     {   console.log('store-muta-state=',state)
         state.weather = weather

     }
 },
 getters:{}
})
```

home.js

```
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import Temperature from '../temperature/Temperature.vue';
import { mapState} from 'vuex';
import '../../custom.scss';

export default {
computed: 
{  ...mapState({ weather: state => state.weather, 
                }),
},
components: {Temperature},
mounted() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => 
    {
        this.$store.dispatch('currentCity', position)
    });
},
};
```

temperature.js

```
export default {
name: 'temperature',
components: {},
props: [ 'weather' ],
data() {
return{
    isShown: false,
        query: '',
        icons: {
            'Rain': require('../../assets/regnerisch.png'),
            'Clear': require('../../assets/sonne.png'),
            'Clouds': require('../../assets/wolkig.png'),
            'Snow': require('../../assets/schnee.png'),
            'Drizzle':require('../../assets/regnerisch.png'),
            'Thunderstorm':require('../../assets/regnerisch.png')
        }
}
},
}
```

home.vue

```
<template>
<b-container fluid >
<!--Navbar-->
 <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between menu-leiste">
 <b-button v-b-toggle.sidebar-left style="background:transparent; 
 border:none">
    <img src="@/assets/menu_button.png" class="menu-button" />
  </b-button>
   <div class="city" v-if="typeof weather.main !='undefined'">
    <strong>{{ weather.name }}</strong>
  </div>
  <b-button v-b-toggle.sidebar-right style="background:transparent; 
 border:none">
    <img src="@/assets/suchen.png" class="suchen" />
  </b-button>
</div>
<!-- sidebar left-->
<b-sidebar id="sidebar-left" title="WEATHER" shadow bg-variant="black" text-
 variant="white">
  <div class="px-3 py-2">
    <router-link to="/">
      <p id="first-line">
 <img src="@/assets/wetter_setting.png" class="wetter-setting-icon"/>Wetter
      </p>
    </router-link>
    <hr style="background-color:white" class="hr" />
    <router-link to="/about">
 <p><img src="@/assets/information.png" class="info-icon" />Über diesen App
      </p>
    </router-link>
    <hr style="background-color:white" class="hr" />
  </div>
 </b-sidebar>
 <!--sidebar right-->
 <b-sidebar id="sidebar-right" right shadow bg-variant="black"
  img src="@/assets/suchen.png" text-variant="white" >
  <div slot="title">
    <img src="@/assets/suchen.png" class="search-icon" />
  </div>
  <div class="px-3 py-2">
    <img src="@/assets/close_white.png" class="close-white-icon"    
 @click="removeType()" />
    <hr style="background-color:white" class="hr2" />
  </div>
</b-sidebar>
<p><strong><div class="row heute">Heute</div></strong></p>
<Temperature  :weather="weather"></Temperature>
<p><strong> <div class="row heute">Nächste 5 Tage</div> </strong></p>

</b-container>
</template>

<script src="./home.js"></script>
<style src="./home.scss" scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

Comment: I have modified the answer with github code link, pls have a look